# Seeking a better Python 3.x+ approach to build multiple different HTMLs within a function

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I've written a function accepts a dict with multiple values. It functions like a "mail merge" inserting values from the dict into different places within the HTML. All of the HTMLs are then returned back in a different dictionary.

This is not very effective for long HTML files. I'm looking for a better approach to insert 20+ values into an HTML that could be 100s of lines long.

A simplified version is included below shows the inefficient approach.

```
def build_html(mail_data):

    html_to_convert = {}

    for data in mail_data:

        export_html = '<html><head><title>'
        export_html += str(data['html_header'])
        export_html += '</title></head><body>'
        export_html += str(data['html_body'])
        export_html += '</body></html>'

        html_to_convert[str(data['unique_id'])] = export_html

    return html_to_convert
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try string formatting rather than concatenation:

```
def build_html(mail_data):

    html_to_convert = {}

    for data in mail_data:
        export_html = '<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>%s</body></html>' % (str(data['html_header']), str(data['html_body']))
        html_to_convert[str(data['unique_id'])] = export_html

    return html_to_convert
```

also where the data isn't a string, rather than converting it to a string you could use the correct formatting flag to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

## Base code for the HTML template

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

# Construct basic webpage template
# Part images will be injected into the body <div> tag
html =""" 
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<script>    
</body>
"""
```

## Make this into a function and reuse for all of your mail items, adding elements to meet your needs

```
soup = Soup(html, 'lxml')
new_tag = soup.new_tag('h2', id='This is a header tag')
soup.div.append(new_tag)
new_tag.string = "Add some text to the h2"
```

## Write it to your local drive if needed

```
# Write html local hard drive
with open('updated.html', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answer - you can bring the format string outside of the function, as it is the same every time. Also, I would recommend using `.format`, rather than `%`. You can use `.format` like this:

```
BUILD_FORMAT = '<html><head><title>{0[html_header]}</title></head><body>{0[html_body]}</body></html>'

def build_html(mail_data):

    html_to_convert = {}

    for data in mail_data:
        export_html = BUILD_FORMAT.format(data)
        html_to_convert[str(data['unique_id'])] = export_html

    return html_to_convert
```

This results in not actually having to manually call `str` at all for the html building. However I don't think there's really any way to make your code go any faster - if this loop is essential, you can't improve your running time much, although I don't know enough about surrounding context to suggest much.